# Can we add a 'dangerous code' tag/marking?

Tags: feature-request

Very frequently code with SQL-injection issues and other issues is posted in SO.
It is of course possible to add a comment explaining the issue, but it would be nice to tag the question/answer as containing a particular security risk, and to have SO put a link with some explanation about the risk at hand.

Similar to the tags, but an extension thereof.

Comment: I think that would qualify rather neatly as a meta-tag, which aren't permitted.

Comment: And you can't tag an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that a tag like that would work without changing the system too much, because currently only questions allow tagging, and answers "inherit" the tags.

I would be in favor of adding an optional markdown for dangerous code to make it stand out from the rest of the page, though.

Answer (score 3):

No, please do not add [meta-tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

A [dangerous](/questions/tagged/dangerous) tag would not be able to stand on its own.

Comment: Dangerous dangerousness endangers danger... (I agree and am trying to work but failing miserably... *sigh*).

Answer (score 3):

There are already enough possible actions for dangerous/wrong code

- Downvote
- Comment
- Delete
- Flag

So there is no need for [dangerous](/questions/tagged/dangerous).

Note you can also edit, but this is often discouraged. It is best if the original poster sees the error and corrects it.